# Creating a simple internet checker

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, network-programming, udp

I've been having an issue with my ISP where my internet has been dropping for a few minutes and then going back up. When I called them they said they only monitor for drops 30 minutes in length or longer. They also said they won't service anything unless a computer is having these problems and is directly connected to their modem.

I have a laptop I've plugged into their modem directly. And I have the rest of my network going through my router. I want each computer to monitor it's connection to the internet and notify me when it goes down in real time.

I wrote a python script that can accomplish this but the problem is that even if I use the timeout property, when the internet goes down (testing this by forcing it down myself) instead of responding that no response has been received in a few seconds, it waits about 30 seconds before announcing and the timing is all over the place.

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
import socket

MESSAGE = bytes("!", "utf-8")
UDP_PORT = 443

def ping(udp_ip):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.settimeout(2)
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (udp_ip, UDP_PORT))

try:    
    ping("google.com")
    time.sleep(3)
except socket.gaierror:
    alert()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce in QPython on my phone. If I turn off Data, remove the sleeps and put a print in the except block, it prints instantly. Not sure if it's different because of the difference of platform.

Comment: The timeout doesn't even seem to be necessary. If I comment it out, I still instantly get "down" printed with Data off. What's `alert`? Could it be delaying reporting?

Comment: alert just plays a beep and outputs some text to a file, it's irrelevant. It can be anything. This program will tell me that things are up instantly. The sleep is so it doesn't alert me constantly. The problem is when the internet goes down there is a 0-60 second delay (seems random) before it reports. It isn't every 3 seconds. This is happening on Windows, Ubuntu and Fedora.

Comment: How are you calling this script? Have you ensured that your script is actually running constantly? Try taking everything else out of the equation. [This](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/59454f574acfa7dd216224738b9b3c52) is able to correctly detect when I cut the wifi on my laptop. I'd just loop in the script instead of looping this via some external script (I'm assuming that's what you're doing).

Comment: The script does detects when I cut the internet out -- but there is a delay. That's the problem I am stuck on.
It specifically locks up on: 
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (ip, UDP_PORT))
The line I added to try and limit the timeout --> 
sock.settimeout(3) didn't seem to do anything to limit that to only 3 seconds like I had hoped. 

After about 15-30 seconds it usually timesout and then the program reports the internet being down as it's supposed to.